# Hide/Show Values Inside TD tags

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide, show

How can I hide or show the value contained inside a TD tag?

E.g:

```
<td id="dateCell<%= i %>">
<%= Html.Encode(row.ActionOn.HasValue ? Html.FormatDateTime(row.ActionOn.Value) : Html.Encode("")) %>
</td>
```

How can I get the encoded value and hide or show it depending on a condition?

Comment: is hiding/showing going to be toggled client side?  what's the condition?

Comment: Yes, it will. Here's the condition: Imagine a dropdownbox in the line with values from 0 to 4. If the value on that box is 3 and you change it to 4, then I must get the value inside the TD and hide it. If you set the box back to 3, I must display it back again.

Comment: IE doesn't like hiding table cells/rows. I'd recommend wrapping the contents in a span, then hiding that as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myDropDown').change(function() {
if($(this).val() == 4) {
    $('#dateCell').hide();
} else if($(this).val() == 3) {
    $('#dateCell').show();
}
```

});

although this will hide the entire td, which isn't necessarily a good practice

Comment: I achieved it by creating a span around the cell value and giving it an unique id. By doing so I could hide only the span instead of the whole td. Thanks anyway for your help.